# ATI ADL - AdapterInfo_Get

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ati

Good evening guys!

I'm currently trying to work with a `Delphi pascal` translation of the `ATI ADL` structure. In brief, this allows me to retrieve information from an ATI/AMD GPU in a system, and potentially control various aspects of it (such as clock and fan speeds).

The translation was taken from [Delphi-Praxis (Google Translated)](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.delphipraxis.net/151628-amd-ati-display-library-adl-sdk-3-0-fuer-pascal.html) or [Delphi-Praxis (not translated)](http://www.delphipraxis.net/151628-amd-ati-display-library-adl-sdk-3-0-fuer-pascal.html) and the provided example application works. I successfully transferred it over to a visual/GUI application, but i'm having trouble getting my head around expanding from the example. I wish to update one of my existing applications with support for ATI GPU's, but i'm having trouble.

My main purpose is to retrieve the `strAdapterName` from `AdapterInfo` inside `adl_structures`. Having not worked with units like this from scratch before, i'm unsure how i define the type itself inside my application. The record structure of `AdapterInfo` is as follows;

```
type
 AdapterInfo = record
  /// Size of the structure.
  iSize : integer;
  /// The ADL index handle. One GPU may be associated with one or two index handles
  iAdapterIndex : integer;
  /// The unique device ID associated with this adapter.
  strUDID : array [0..ADL_MAX_PATH] of char;
  /// The BUS number associated with this adapter.
  iBusNumber : integer;
  /// The driver number associated with this adapter.
  iDeviceNumber : integer;
  /// The function number.
  iFunctionNumber : integer;
  /// The vendor ID associated with this adapter.
  iVendorID : integer;
  /// Adapter name.
  strAdapterName : array [0..ADL_MAX_PATH] of char;
  /// Display name. For example, "\\Display0" for Windows or ":0:0" for Linux.
  strDisplayName : array [0..ADL_MAX_PATH] of char;
  /// Present or not; 1 if present and 0 if not present.
  iPresent : integer;
 // @}
end;
```

I'm honestly struggling to figure out exactly what i need to define in the `type` section of my application, and moreover, to actually get something workable.

There's very little delphi-specific information on the ADL library (the only information was the Delphi-praxis link above) and while it's well documented in it's SDK format, i unfortunately lack the knowledge to be able to translate between languages (e.g. i can't read `C` or `C++` code and translate what data type variables are).

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me you just need to add the adl_structures unit to your app, and then declare a variable of type `AdapterInfo`, like `var AInfo: AdapterInfo;`. You've posted what seems to be a perfectly good Delphi declaration above, unless the ATI library is non-Unicode (in which case the `Char` arrays should be changed to `AnsiChar`).

Comment: @KenWhite That declaration is from `adl_structures` itself, but the issue is that in the sample application, it reports temperatures, and assigns a function in the type section along with a variable to point to this function. This function hooks into `adl_structures` to retrieve the temperature. I'm having trouble understanding how i'd define the type function in order to work with `AdapterInfo`, particularly what variable i need to assign in said function. Everything i've tried to declare returns a `null` value (i.e. no value appears in the label i'm trying to output it to).

Comment: Please see this thread for some answers regarding ADL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105804/delphi-calling-amd-adl-c-dll